# Как заблокировать ссылки во фрейме и обрамить в свою?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, ссылки

Есть на сайте `iframe` подтягиваемый с другого сайта, в котором содержатся ссылки.

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" ><iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/sc/?u=aGF3YWlpaXNsYW5kcmV0cmVhdHxpbnwxNTB8NnwyfHx5ZXN8MjB8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fHllc3xubw==&amp;ve=171114" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:900px; height:150px"></iframe></a>
```

Вопрос: как назначить всем ссылкам `javascript:void(0);` и обрамить `iframe` в собственную ссылку, чтобы по ней переходила туда, куда я укажу?

Comment: никак, и в принципе и не должно

Answer (score 1):

@Grundy я нашел способ - наложил ссылку поверх фрейма абсолютным позиционированием и подогнал под его размеры - теперь моя ссылка показывается поверх и визуально ссылки фрейма теперь не видны!